# I ned a while loop statment that makes the calculations loop and ask again

Tags: java, loops

im not too sure how you add a loop statement to this. I want it to be a while loop that makes it do that the calculations repeat after finishing. I've tried but it just keeps on giving me errors. ive tried doing While statements but just will not work im not sure how you set it up as my teacher did not explain very well

```
import com.godtsoft.diyjava.DIYWindow;

public class Calculator extends DIYWindow {

    public Calculator() {
        
        
            
        // getting number one
        double number1 = promptForDouble("Enter a number");
        
        //getting number2
        int number2 = promptForInt("Enter an integer");
        
        //getting what to do with operation
        print("What do you want to do with these numbers?\nAdd\tSubtract\tMultiply\tDivide");
        String operation = input();
        //declaring variable here so the same one can be used
        double answer = 0;
        switch(operation) {
        case "add":
            answer = number1 + number2;
            print(number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + answer);
            break;
        case "subtract":
            answer = number1 - number2;
            print(number1 + " - " + number2 + " = " + answer);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            answer = number1 * number2;
            print(number1 + " * " + number2 + " = " + answer);
            break;
        case "divide":
            
            try {   
                answer = number1 / number2;     
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException e) {
                print("A number cannot be divided by 0.");  
            }
            print(number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + answer);
            break;
        }
        
        
        double double1 = promptForDouble("Enter a number");
        double double2 = promptForDouble("Enter another number");
        double double3 = promptForDouble("Enter one last number");
        print("What do you want to do with these numbers?\nAdd\tSubtrack\tMultiply\tDivide");
        String operation2 = input();
        double answer2 = 0;
        switch(operation2) {
        case "add":
            answer2 = double1 + double2 + double3;
            print(double1 + " + " + double2 + " + " + double3 + " = " + answer2);
            break;
        case "subtract":
            answer2 = double1 - double2 - double3;
            print(double1 + " - " + double2 + " - " + double3 + " = " + answer2);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            answer2 = double1 * double2 * double3;
            print(double1 + " * " + double2 + " * " + double3 + " = " + answer2);
            break;
        case "divide":
        
            try {   
                answer2 = double1 / double2 / double3;      
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException e) {
                print("A number cannot be divided by 0.");  
            }
            print(double1 + " / " + double2 + " / " + double3 + " = " + answer2);
            break;
        }
        
        want it to loop after the code on top 
        
        }
    
        
    
    
    
    private double promptForDouble(String prompt) {
        double number1 = 0;
        print(prompt);
        String number = input();
        
        try {   
            number1 = Double.parseDouble(number);   
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            print("That is not a number. Please enter a number.");
            number1 = promptForDouble(prompt);  
        }
        return number1;
    }
    

    private int promptForInt(String prompt) {
        int number2 = 0;
        print(prompt);
        String number = input();
        
        try {
        
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(number); }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            print("That is not an integer. Enter an integer.");
            number2 = promptForInt(prompt); }
        return number2;
    }
    
    
        
        
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calculator();

    }

}
```

Comment: package com.godtsoft.diyjava does not exist

Comment: Not an answer, but it is very unusual to do real work in the constructor. Suggest you write a doOneCalculation() method and do your input and calcs in that method. Then call it from main() doing your looping there.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your main method:

```
while (true)
{
   Thread.sleep(1000); // optional, make some deplay for more nature
   new Calculator();
}
```

Or you can wrap all body blocks of the constructor inside the above while statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add a named loop around the block you want to repeat (the line starting with `String operation = input()` and add a default case to break out:

```
outerLoop:
while (true) {
    String operation = input();
    ...
    switch
        // cases
        ...
        default:
            break outerLoop;
    }
}
```

which will repeat the block until something other than one of the 4 operations is entered.